# Android: ProgressBar in ProgressDialog not Animating

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created one AsyncTask class for fetching data from background (Accessing database).

In **onPreExecute()** method, I create one progress dialog

```
        try {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "",
                    "Please wait...", true);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

        } catch (final Throwable th) {
            // TODO
        }
```

And in onpostExecute()

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            pinPoint();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

My updated class,

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            clust = getPinPointClusters();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    plotClusters(clust);
                }
            });

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Here pinpoint() method will get some data from server and pin the points in map.
But The progressBar in ProgressDialog is not animating...
Please provide me the best way...

Thanks

Comment: I didnt use pinPoint() in doInBackGround() because , this method will affect the UI

Comment: does the method getPinPointClusters() trying to update the UI??

Comment: @Haresh Chaudhary, No it will return only GeoCluster object

Comment: @Haresh Chaudhary, But plotCluster() will update the UI

Comment: try this way..change this runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...to activityname.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()...

Comment: and what's then pinPoint();
???that you have put in onpostExecute()..??

Comment: i tried that, but same exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14337/discussion-between-sridhar-and-haresh-chaudhary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to put the **pinPoint() method** in the `doInBackground method` and the lines of the method **pinPoint()** which are ***affecting the UI*** can be kept under this method::

```
activityname.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() 
         {
        // Put here the line which is changing the UI.          
     }
});
```

**Example :** When any line attempts to change the UI in the doInBackground , do this way:

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) 
   {
     .
     .
     .
     .     
    activityname.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() 
                 {
                   eg. linearLayout.addView(ChildView);         
             }
        });
     .
     .
     . 
   }
```

Now,you have to just ***dismiss*** the `ProgressDialog` from the **onPostExecute()** method.

Comment: @Haresh Chaudhary, I got some runtime exception like, cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare

Comment: @Paresh Mayani, I got some runtime exception like, cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare

Comment: @Sridhar because you are trying to update UI while doing threading. Its not possible, You can either implement `runOnUiThread()` or use implement `onProgressUpdate()` of AsyncTask.

Comment: What code are you Using..please can you post it in the Question Section

Comment: @Paresh Mayani, please see my updated class in the Question section. I implement runONUiThread()

Comment: I have stated Above a example in my Answer about how to update the UI..you have to suppose in my example that you are trying to add child View from the doInBackground

Comment: @Haresh Chaudhary, what will i do to overcome this

Answer (score 1):

The 'animating' occurs on the main UI thread. `onPostExecute` also runs on the UI thread so you are effectively blocking it when you make your call to your server. Move `pinPoint` to `doInBackground` so that it executes on the background thread, allowing the progress dialog to keep animating.

When running your code on later versions of android (Honeycomb [Android 3.0] onwards) this will also throw a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) when on strict mode.

If `pinPoint` requires changes to the UI, you need to separate out the network call into `doInBackground` (+ data manipulation) and only UI changes into `onPostExecute`. You can hold a reference on the task to the data or pass it through as a result.

You can also make use of the `publishProgress` method, to publish multiple UI changes during `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

You have create different functions for fetching data and updating UI part

```
    private class FetchRSSFeeds extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
            Utilities.arrayRSS = objRSSFeed.FetchRSSFeeds(Constants.Feed_URL);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            // Setting data to list adaptar
            setListData();
            txtTitle.setText(Utilities.RSSTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nirali, but I got some runtime exception